# Change default show() / hide() animation behavior in jquery

Tags: jquery

I want to have a div show from left to right on hover of a div, and retract from right to left on hide. How do you change the default show and hide functions? It appears that for show, both the height and width of the div are affected, and the same goes for hide. Is there a way to only effect the width?

Comment: Duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1428321/change-the-jquery-show-hide-animation?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

Here is code to change show()/ hide() animation of jquery dialog box:

```
        $('#dialog1').dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            show: 'slide', 
            hide: 'explode',
            buttons: { 'Close': function () { $(this).dialog('close'); } },
            closeOnEscape: true,
            resizable: false
        });
```

Comment: that's completely irrelevant to the question