# jQuery .fadeIn() on page load?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, fadein

I'm trying to set up some code so that I have a  that is hidden at first but then fades in after the page is loaded.

I have the following HTML code:

```
<div class="hidden">
<p>This is some text.</p>
</div>
```

Then I also have this CSS code, which hides the `<div>`.

```
div.hidden
{
    display: none
}
```

Finally, I have my jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('div').fadeOut(1);
    $('div').removeClass('hidden');
    $('div').fadeIn(1000);
});
```

What I was hoping would happen was that the first .fadeOut() would fade out the , the removeClass would stop the CSS from hiding it, and the final .fadeIn() would fade it back onto the page.  Unfortunately, this did not work.

You can view the code here:[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Bm62Y/)

So can someone please tell me how to keep a `<div>` hidden until a page loads, and then fade it in using jQuery?

Thanks!

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The problem is `fadeIn` works on hidden elements, when you remove the hidden class before the `fadeIn()` is called the element is fully displayed so there is nothing to to `fadeIn()`

It should be

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('div.hidden').fadeIn(1000).removeClass('hidden');
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/2nzHT/)

Comment: All you need is,
`$(document).ready(function () {
        $('div.hidden').fadeIn(1000);
 });`

Answer (score 5):

HTML Code:

```
<div class="toshow" style="display:none;">
    This is some text.
</div>
```

jquery Code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('div.toshow').fadeIn(2200);
    // OR $('div.toshow').show(2200);
    // OR $('div.toshow').slideDown("slow");
});
```

[Change the jquery show()/hide() animation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1428321/change-the-jquery-show-hide-animation)

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/Bm62Y/5/

```
//If you do not want the "hidden" class to be still around
$(function() {
    $('div').fadeIn(1000).removeClass('hidden');
});

//If you don't mind it, then you can just do fadeIn
$(function() {
    $('div').fadeIn(1000);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//image fade in
    //set image display none
        $("img").css("display", "none");
    //call the image with fadeIn effect
    $("img").fadeIn(5000 , function(){
        $(this).css("display","normal");
    });
```

I have experimented on images .You can try on text too..